# match all values in an array php

Tags: php

The user can search for something using select and checkbox forms. The data is sent in GET variables. 
I'm collected all the possible values in variables and putting it into an array:
    `$term_taxomony_ids_array = array($term_taxonomy_id_m, $term_taxonomy_id_l,  $term_taxonomy_id_t_1,  $term_taxonomy_id_t_2, $term_taxonomy_id_t_3, $term_taxonomy_id_t_4, $term_taxonomy_id_t_5, $term_taxonomy_id_t_6, $term_taxonomy_id_t_7, $term_taxonomy_id_t_8);`
print_r($term_taxomony_ids_array); would then give
eg:

```
Array (
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 14
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
    [4] => 9
    [5] =>
    [6] => 2
    [7] =>
    [8] =>
    [9] =>
)
```

How would I make this array simpler but leaving out the empty results altogether (as suggested in a comment)?
I need to find the 'places' in the database who match **all** the criteria that was selected. 
My database table is set up so I have two columns. 
1. Object_id 2. term_taxonomy_id. 
The term_taxonomy_id are the values in the array. 
eg my table looks like this

```
Object id  term_taxonomy_id
    2            12
    2             3
    3            12
    3            14
    3             9
    3             2
    4             5
    5             9
```

So only object_id '3' matches all the terms in the array - 12, 14, 9, 2
How would I run a query to find this result?
I'm using a mysql database, phpmyadmin and my site is built on wordpress.
Thanks

Comment: You should probably tag your question with the DB platform you're using.

Comment: so `[0] => 12` is taxonomy ID #12, and you want to retrieve object ID #2?

Comment: Because of the way this is setup, the easiest way would be to query for the object id of each of the taxonomy values selected and find which object id exists in all of the groups.

Comment: @MarcB There are 4 taxonomy values and OP wants only the object id that matches all values. Which object id `3` is the only one.

Comment: What about the empty array elements (`[2] =>, [3] =>, [5] =>, [7] =>, [8] =>, [9] =>`)? Ignore them altogether, and use only elements that have values assigned (in this example only elements that have the values `12, 14, 9, 2`)?

Comment: I've edited the question. Please advise a better way to do this. Thanks

Comment: How do I create an array that ignores empty terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use IN, Combined with COUNT() and having/GROUP.

```
$array = array_filter(array_unique($array));
$count = count($array);
$sql = "SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field IN (" . implode(',', $array) . ") GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = " . $count;
```

The SQL might be a bit off (you might have to re-order having and group).

Answer (score 4):

Basically:

```
SELECT objectID, COUNT(term_taxonomy_id) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
WHERE term_taxonomy_id  IN (2, 9, 14, 12)
GROUP BY objectID
HAVING cnt = 4
```

find all the objectIDs that have one or more matching taxonomy IDs, but then return only the object IDs that have FOUR matching taxonomy IDs.

Comment: my final query that worked was '$count = count($term_taxomony_ids_array2); // echo $count;
   
   $query = "SELECT object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN ($term_taxomony_ids_array3) GROUP BY object_id HAVING COUNT(*) = $count";' Thanks for your help.